# "Source pixel format is not supported by the filter" error in AForge.NET

Tags: c#, aforge

I'm trying to apply Bradleys thresholding algorithm in Aforge

Everytime I try to process the image  I get the exception below

> throw new UnsupportedImageFormatException( "Source pixel format is not
>   supported by the filter." );

I grayscaled the image using the below method before applying the algorithm

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Grayscale filter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
    Bitmap grayImage = filter.Apply(img);

    pictureBox1.Image = grayImage;
}
```

The code for the algorithm call

```
public void bradley(ref Bitmap tmp)
{  
    BradleyLocalThresholding filter = new BradleyLocalThresholding();
    filter.ApplyInPlace(tmp);
}
```

I tried the sane image in image processing lab and it did work but not on my system.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that your `bradley` method really receives the grayscale filtered image? When I run your code and apply the `BradleyLocalThresholding` filter directly on `grayImage` in `button2_Click` (before updating `pictureBox1.Image`), the Bradley filtering works as desired.

Answer (score 5):

I've used the following code to get better information in cases like this.  It doesn't fix the problem, but it at least gives more helpful information than AForge does by itself.

```
namespace AForge.Imaging.Filters {

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides utility methods to assist coding against the AForge.NET 
    /// Framework.
    /// </summary>
    public static class AForgeUtility {

        /// <summary>
        /// Makes a debug assertion that an image filter that implements 
        /// the <see cref="IFilterInformation"/> interface can 
        /// process an image with the specified <see cref="PixelFormat"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterInfo">The filter under consideration.</param>
        /// <param name="format">The PixelFormat under consideration.</param>
        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        public static void AssertCanApply(
            this IFilterInformation filterInfo, 
            PixelFormat format) {
            Debug.Assert(
                filterInfo.FormatTranslations.ContainsKey(format),
                string.Format("{0} cannot process an image " 
                    + "with the provided pixel format.  Provided "
                    + "format: {1}.  Accepted formats: {2}.",
                    filterInfo.GetType().Name,
                    format.ToString(),
                    string.Join( ", ", filterInfo.FormatTranslations.Keys)));
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, you can use it as:

```
public void bradley(ref Bitmap tmp)
{  
    BradleyLocalThresholding filter = new BradleyLocalThresholding();
    filter.AssertCanApply( tmp.PixelFormat );
    filter.ApplyInPlace(tmp);
}
```

Comment: @levi unfortunately, while this helped me figure out an issue (I don't remember by now which one), it was not the issue in the question.

Comment: i had the same issue, the problem is in the pixel format, the format supported seems to be 8bpp indexed.

Thanks a lot for help method, that piece of code save me a lot of work